# How to check if a JSON response element is an array?

Tags: javascript, json

I am receiving the next JSON response

```
    {
    "timetables":[
        {"id":87,"content":"B","language":"English","code":"en"},                                                
        {"id":87,"content":"a","language":"Castellano","code":"es"}],
    "id":6,
    "address":"C/Maestro José"
    }
```

I would like to achieve the next pseudo code functionality

```
for(var i in json) {            
    if(json[i]  is Array) {
    // Iterate the array and do stuff
    } else {
    // Do another thing
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There are other methods but, to my knowledge, this is the most reliable:

```
function isArray(what) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(what) === '[object Array]';
}
```

So, to apply it to your code:

```
for(var i in json) {                    
    if(isArray(json[i])) {
    // Iterate the array and do stuff
    } else {
    // Do another thing
    }
}
```

Comment: There is now a native function in JavaScript that will do this ([`Array.isArray(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)), though older browsers will still need to rely on this as a polyfill.

Answer (score 30):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

```
if(Array.isArray(json[i])){
    // true
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function isArray(ob) {
  return ob.constructor === Array;
}
```

Comment: This will work in most situations but it will fail when you're testing an array from a different window/frame since the constructor will be different.