# format which support flash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an json which stored as toc.js for eg the json is like this

```
[{ "id":"205","name":"apple", "description":"fruit"},
 {"id":"206","name":"radio","description":"Electronics"},]
```

and i am using `$.getJSON( url,callback)` in my code.
but the result is in object format, i get the output in array format so it can be used in the flash. 
I'm trying to grab data from a JSON on an flash but the flash doesn't support JSON-P output.

Comment: So?  What's the question?  How do you return an array in JSON?

Comment: For reference, this technically is invalid JSON.  The trailing commas (after "fruit", "Electronics", and the final curly brace) shouldn't be there, and some JSON parsers (Webkit's among them, last i checked) will choke on them.

Answer (score 2):

```
var foo = '[{ "id":"205","name":"apple", "description":"fruit",}, {"id":"206","name":"radio","description":"Electronics"}]'

foo = JSON.parse(foo);

Object.prototype.toString.call(foo) === '[object Array]'
```

`$.getJSON` will call just that (`JSON.parse`) after validating the string as JSON. Make sure what the server sends you back by calling:

```
$.get(url, callback, 'text');
```

and lookup the response data within the callback.

Comment: my flash team is asking that the output is in javascript object so they cannot support it they need in array format

Answer (score 0):

Here you go fella :) [Assign data from jQuery getJSON to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442487/assign-data-from-jquery-getjson-to-array)

Comment: i dont need this.i want json p to be converted and result the same in json array