# create string from JSON values in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, string, google-books

I'd like to create a string of ISBNs from a JSON object to search multiple books in Google Books.

I can get the ISBNs by parsing Google Books' JSON with this path:

```
volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier
```

(Here I'm doing that to get a simple book list: [jsfiddle.net/LyNfX](http://jsfiddle.net/LyNfX) )

How do I string together each value in order to get this query structure, where each ISBN is preceded by "isbn:", and after the first one they are separated by "OR"

```
https://www.google.com/search?btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&q=Springfield+isbn:1416549838+OR+isbn:068482535X+OR+isbn:0805093079+OR+isbn:0306810328
```

Comment: How do you get the second ISBN?

Comment: is the fiddle I use the jquery template plugin and {{each}}

Comment: Have you got this working?

Comment: see the fiddle. It successfully lists the info for each book. what I was looking for was creating a string from that same info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from an array of ISBN strings called `list`:

```
list.map(function(v){return "isbn:"+v;}).join("+OR+")
```

As for building your list of ISBN's which I understand to be the `identifier` prop in your `industryIdentifiers` (if `industryIdentifier` is a bona fide `Array`):

```
var list = [];
volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers.forEach(function(e,i){list.push(e.identifier);});
```

You could also just build the final string in one fell swoop and not build an array at all, but this means extra logic to prevent inserting an extra delimiter (`+OR+` being the delimiter)

```
var output = "";
volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers.forEach(function(e,i){output += "isbn:"+e.identifier+"+OR+";});
output.slice(0,-4); // clear out last +OR+
```

Comment: great. how would I get the volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers.identifier 's into the array to start?

Comment: I don't know what the format of that is. Could you post it or something?

Comment: in my fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/LyNfX] , I use the jQuery template plugin to create html for each book like this:  var mylist = "{{each items}}" + "<div class=book id=" + theid + ">"
    + "<p><b>title</b> is ${volumeInfo.title}"
    + "<p><b>author</b> is ${volumeInfo.authors}"
    + "<p><b>isbn10</b> is ${volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier}"             
    + "</div>{{/each}}";

Comment: so what I need now is to get each volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers.identifier into an array, rather than printing it into html. then I can do your list.map ... on that array -- if I'm understanding correctly?

Comment: on this related q, it looks like this was the approach -- is this on the right track? 
 for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            things[i]=[data[i].id,String(data[i].username),String(data[i].things)];
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442487/assign-data-from-jquery-getjson-to-array

Comment: Trying to use Firebug Lite in a fiddle is a road to misery. Use this URL for the fiddle instead: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ZwqWS/ When I opened in chrome web inspector there was a series of cross domain errors

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrayOfISBNs = [123,456,789...];
var result = "isbn:" + arrayOfISBNs.join(" OR isbn:")
```

Just use array join.